# Content Presenter in WPF exception

Tags: wpf, contentpresenter, contentproperty

Exception using content presenter

Type 'System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter' does not have a content property.
 Specify the name of the property to set, or add a ContentPropertyAttribute or
 TypeConverterAttribute on the type.

Below is the XAML

```
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Content="{Binding Series}" Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" Checked="CheckSeries_Checked" Unchecked="CheckSeries_UnChecked" />

                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
```

Comment: how do you get it - could you post the XAML resulting in the exception?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set the `ContentPresenter.Content` property implicitly by setting the inner text of the `ContentPresenter` control:

```
<ContentPresenter>
    MyContent
</ContentPresenter>
```

Instead you should set it like this

```
<ContentPresenter Content="MyContent" />
```

You're getting this error because `ContentPresenter` doesn't have the `ContentProperty` Attribute which tells the XAML parser to set the inner text as the value for its `Content` property.

Comment: I am not using ContentPresenter  any where in my code, but still am getting the XAML error

Answer (score 0):

Well the only guess possible in this case is that you are trying to assign "content" property instead of "Content" with capital C. If it's not then post your XAML code please.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"

Since it is a datatemplate, and the content will be set by the ItemSource used?